# Extract() increases sum of values?

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, spatial-analyst, sp

I am using the Landscan grid to calculate the number people within Vietnamese communes. First I masked the data with the GADM boundary. Then I used extract() to calculate the population by commune and saved as a sp file. I converted sp file into a data frame. The code is below.

```
pop <- raster("w001001.adf") 
crop <- crop(pop, gadm)
mask1 <- mask(crop, gadm) # this is so that the next step is a bit quicker
vn <- extract(mask1, gadm, fun=sum, na.rm=T, sp=T)
dta <- as.data.frame(vn) 

sum(dta$mask1) # sum of data frame ~ 82 millions
cellStats(mask1, sum) # sum of raster value ~ 95 millions
```

I think the sum of either the raster or the data frame should give me the entire population of Vietnam and therefore, be identical. However, the two sums are different. The sum of the raster values give me 82 millions (which is most likely correct) and the sum of the data frame yields 95 million people... Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Update:

```
cell <-extract(mask1, gadm, cellnumbers=T, na.rm=T)
> sum(duplicated(cell))
[1] 7
> cell[duplicated(cell)]
[[1]]
    cell value
 1332229 47417

[[2]]
    cell value
 1332228 38578

[[3]]
    cell value
 1332227 41256

[[4]]
    cell value
 1329593 27005

[[5]]
    cell value
 1332233 41888

[[6]]
       cell value
[1,] 248323 29696
[2,] 249202 28011

[[7]]
   cell value
 248324 21301
```

Update 2:

The Landscan data is available at https://landscan.ornl.gov/landscan-datasets. However, there is an approval process that takes a few days before the data can be downloaded. I'm trying to do the exact same thing with the F162004 DMSP Nightlight value which can downloaded from https://ngdc.noaa.gov/eog/dmsp/downloadV4composites.html.

The GADM boundary file can be loaded directly in r

```
library(raster)
gadm <- getData('GADM', country='VN', level=3) # VN
```

Comment: Your assumption is only true, I think, if none of the polygons overlap at all. If there are overlapping polygons then some raster cells will be double-counted. But going from 82m to 95m would be a lot of overlap. Try using the `cellNumbers` argument (without the sum function to get every extracted pixel) and see if cell numbers are repeated.

Comment: @Spacedman Thank you so much for your help! I tried using cellNumbers and extract() returned a list (I updated the code above). There are only 7 duplicates. I also compared district's populations with the official statistics from the government. Everything seems really off for the big cities. Do you have any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Not without pointing us to the data or showing the same behaviour with some data we can have.

Comment: @Spacedman I've included another update above with the data I'm using. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: The lights are a 1Gb download, but I've got the same behaviour using the WorldPop Vietnam 1km population data. https://www.worldpop.org/geodata/listing?id=74 - sum of the raster is just under 99m and the sum of the extract over gadm is 118m. Will investigate later.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have lots of small polygons and by default `small=TRUE` is set. In this case when a polygon is so small (or perhaps oddly shaped) that it doesn't cover the centre of a grid square, then `extract` does something else (its not clear exactly what) to get a value for that polygon.

With the worldpop data I get:

```
> vn <- extract(mask1, gadm, fun=sum, na.rm=T, sp=T)
> sum(pop[],na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 99488591
> sum(vn$vnm_ppp_2020_1km_Aggregated)
[1] 118414408
```

which is like what you have, but using `small=FALSE` does this:

```
> vn_nosmall <- extract(mask1, gadm, fun=sum, na.rm=T, sp=T, small=FALSE)
> sum(vn_nosmall$vnm_ppp_2020_1km_Aggregated)
[1] NA
> sum(vn_nosmall$vnm_ppp_2020_1km_Aggregated,na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 98847054
```

First, the small polygons have `NA` for their value. I can find out what their population was in the default, and that totals up to:

```
> sum(vn$vnm_ppp_2020_1km_Aggregated[
      is.na(vn_nosmall$vnm_ppp_2020_1km_Aggregated)
    ])
[1] 19567354
```

which is roughly the difference between the raster total and the larger total. The excess is some double counting from these small polygons.

`help(extract)` has some options that can fix this, see `weights` for example, but this involves intersecting every polygon with the grid to add up all the little bits and can be very slow.

Alternatively you could make your grid on a finer scale so that small polygons do cover at least one grid square centre. You could do this by dividing each cell into four (eg using `disaggregate`) but remember to divide any *count* variables by four (but not any *density* variables which are constant per unit area).

Comment: `exactextractr::exact_extract(pop, sf::st_as_sf(gadm), 'sum')` should handle this without cropping the raster or worrying about the relative sizes of the polygons.

Comment: I always forgot these things exist. If only the `raster` package was a bit more agile. See also the `stars` package and a bunch of others.

Comment: I really can't thank you enough for such thorough answer! I am new to spatial data so it has been frustrating. This is incredibly helpful! Again, thank you!!